# The emerald, the shamrock, the Blarney

Tags: vocabulary

> Nature bestowed all her gifts with a smile
>   The emerald, the shamrock, **the Blarney**
>   When you can buy all these wonderful things
>   Then you can buy Killarney
>   ([How Can You Buy Killarney?](http://www.metrolyrics.com/how-can-you-buy-killarney-lyrics-bing-crosby.html))

What is the proper name ‘Blarney,’ a wonderful thing for the singer?

Comment: I'm not sure but all these wonderful things seem to refer to Ireland. Killarney and Blarney are places in Ireland. The shamrock is the national symbol of Ireland. And the nickname of Ireland is the Emerald Isle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blarney):

> By kissing the Blarney Stone at Blarney Castle, it is claimed that one can receive the "Gift of the Gab" (eloquence, or skill at flattery or persuasion).

I'm not terribly familiar with the song (or the country, for that matter) so it's quite possible I'm on the wrong track, but it seems to me that 'Blarney' in this context might be a slang term for the 'gift of gab' referenced above.

Edit: Alternative explanation: 'blarney' actually means 'the little field' in Irish. When you take that with the line 'Nature bestowed all her gifts with a smile', it fits in with the rest of the list, which are natural things.

Comment: You had it right the first time: blarney is the gift of the gab, or the gab itself - says M-W: "talk that is not true but that is nice and somewhat funny and that may be used to trick you"